# yii2 elasticsearch | Make sure a GET /_nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

I installed elasticsearch and try to make a request, but in response I get an error

```
Cluster autodetection did not find any active node. Make sure a GET /_nodes reguest on the hosts defined in the config returns the "http_address" field for each node.
```

when i run the command `CURL -X GET http://localhost:9200`

```
{
  "name" : "DS12IC4",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_denysmaksiura",
  "cluster_uuid" : "YzFUXRS6SPmObJcC4bv_ag",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.5",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "78990e9",
    "build_date" : "2019-11-13T20:04:24.100411Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

my main.php file

```
'elasticsearch' => [
            'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
            'nodes' => [
                ['http_address' => 'localhost:9200'],
                // configure more hosts if you have a cluster
            ],
        ],
```

my controller

```
$model = new SearchAllForms();
        $dataProvider = $model->globalSearch(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        echo"<pre>";
        var_dump($dataProvider->getModels());
        exit;
```

my model(testing request)

```
$query = $this::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'key' => 'id'
        ]);

        $query->query(['match' => ['name' => 'Гидротест']]);

        return $dataProvider;
```

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

there is 2.1-dev version available in yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch.  this  problem is solved there.check this version please.